# Bluces en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo un ejercicio de un taller de Python donde me indica que el usuario debe ingresar dos datos iniciales, sucursales y pacientes, si las sucursales son inferiores a uno se debe volver a ingresar los datos. Después de que se ingrese un valor correcto, debe numerar las sucursales ( para esto utilice un array vacio) donde se les debe agregar las cantidades de cierto medicamento, pero si esas cantidades son inferiores a 1 se deben repetir hasta ingresar un valor mayor a uno. Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora, funciona bien hasta el segundo while (donde valida las cantidades) pues si ingreso 0, efectivamente reinicia el bucle, pero sigue dejando ingresar cantidades y necesito que se rompa al momento de que las cantidades se ingresen bien:

```
 datos = True
exitencias = True

while datos:
    m = int(input())
    n = int(input())
    if m > 1:
        datos = False
    else:
        datos = True

sucursales = []

while exitencias:
    for i in range(m):
        sucursales.append(int(input()))
    minimo = min(sucursales)
    if minimo >= 1:
        exitencias = False
    else:
        exitencias = True
```

Este es el enunciado del ejercicio "... Para ello, el sistema debe recibir como entrada la cantidad de sucursales (n) para la entrega de medicamentos seguido de la cantidad total de pacientes a atender (m), si la cantidad de sucursales es menor a 1 se debe leer nuevamente ambos valores hasta que se ingrese un n válido. Luego, para las n sucursales (numeradas de 1 a n) se debe leer la cantidad de existencias actuales del medicamento y esta debe ser mayor o igual a 1, y en caso de que no se cumpla se debe leer valores hasta que se ingrese uno válido..."

Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Intentaste agregar un break al bucle? es lo ideal

Comment: Si, lo puse dentro del if minimo >= 1 , pero sigue ejecutado el bucle, y al ponerlo dentro del else de ese mismo if, rompe el bucle y no deja seguir ingresando valores

Comment: Sucursales es una lista? e intentas validar que cada uno de los valores sea mayor a 0? Podrías usar un for para esto, o cambiar el if por:
if minimo != 0:
    ejecuta

Comment: Si, sucursales es una lista vacía, donde en el for del while existencias, me da la opcion de agregar las cantidades dependiendo el rango de m que se supone son las sucursales que ingresa el usuario. Ya puse el if minimo != 0 , pero sigue ejecutando el bucle

Comment: La condición no se cumple. tal vez porque no estás recorriendo cada elemento, Realmente no entiendo que hace "min(sucursales)" tal vez podrías explicarme para ayudarte más

Comment: Me muestra el valor mínimo de la lista que ingresa el usuario.

Comment: @CamiloCuitiva. Se sabe que `min()` retorna el mínimo. La pregunta es ¿qué significa ese mínimo?

Comment: @CandidMoe es para guardar el número minimo de la lista y de esa manera poderle validar el if, donde si hay un valor menor que 1 me reinicie el bucle.

Answer (score 0):

**El error de tu codigo tiene dos causas:**

1. las condicionales del segundo bucle while estan fuera del for del
   input por lo que tu condicion de medicamentos mayor igual a 1 solo
   se evalua posterior a ingresar los datos.
2. El ciclo for esta dentro del while, pero debe ser al reves, el while
   deberia estar dentro del for, para ejecutar la entry indefinidamente
   hasta que cumpla la condicion.

Esto se corrige de la siguiente manera, en 3 pasos.

1. Eliminar el while de afuera.

```
for i in range(m):
    sucursales.append(int(input()))
minimo = min(sucursales)
if minimo >= 1:
    exitencias = False
else:
    exitencias = True
```

2. Anidar el while al for para recibir y evaluar el entry de
   medicamentos para una sucursal indefinidamente.

```
    for i in range(m):
        while True:
            sucursales.append(int(input()))
            if minimo >= 1:
               exitencias = False
            else:
               exitencias = True
```

3. Reemplazar el agregado a la lista por una variable que reciba el
   input y usarla para evaluar la condicion.

```
    for i in range(m):
        while exitencias :
            entrada = int(input())
            if entrada >= 1:
               exitencias = False
            else:
               exitencias = True
```

**MEJORANDO EL CODIGO**

Este codigo se puede simplificar si se elimina else y se reemplaza la sentencia del del if por un break, como tambien, reemplazar la variable existencias por un True

```
    for i in range(m):
        while True:
            entrada = int(input())
            if entrada >= 1:
               break
```

Finalmente, podrias desafiarte a agregar condiciones a tu codigo para que pueda controlar inputs erroneos y no se termine el programa por un error de sintaxys empleando condicionales.